# Amazon Simple Notification Service to send SMS in asp.net

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I want to send sms to mobile devices using amazon sns in asp.net without creating any topic and subsciption. Can anybody suggest me some helpful material or link. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is simply to send SMS to a mobile number, you may be better off using an api like twilio, you need a topic AND a subscription to use SNS. With twilio you can simply send an SMS to any mobile number you want - there are limits on the quantity you can send within a timeframe, and spamming is prohibited, but assuming that's not your primary goal twilio may be an inexpensive and easy-to-use option for you.

https://www.twilio.com/sms

Comment: Thanks Brennan. But is there any possibility if I only want to use Amazon-SNS for this purpose?

Comment: Not if you don't set up a topic and then have users subscribe to it

Comment: You can send sms without anyone subscribing through the console, so you can do it also through their SDK.

Comment: Yes, but three years ago when the question was asked and answered, this was not true - just for the record.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with AWS SNS. When you create a PublishRequest you will see a property for PhoneNumber. Just enter the phone number and publish the message as you normally would.

Important thing to note: the phone number has to be in E.164 format. example: +14155552671